# How to remove natural margin when no float is listed

Tags: html, css

I was testing around with divs and buttons and stuff, an I noticed that when I remove a float, it adds a natural margin.
When I inputed this

```
body {
background: gray;
}

        button {
        font-size: 17px;
        color: white;
        margin-left: 0px;
        margin-right: 0px;
        border: 0;
        width: 100px;
        height: 40px;
        text-align: center;
        vertical-align: middle;
        background: rgba(0,0,0,0.0);
        transition: background 400ms;
        -webkit-transition: background 400ms;
        }

        button:hover {
        background: rgba(0,255,255,0.3);
        }
```

JSFiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/uBBeX/

(You can highlight the small margin between the buttons)

How can I remove the "natural" margin without using floats?

**Note: I just want to remove the margin for the buttons, nothing else.**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `<button>` elements in your fiddle, at least in Chrome (which I am currently using), has a default `display: inline-block;` style. Adjacent `inline-block` elements (as well as `inline` elements) are going to allow the whitespace between the elements to render (your whitespace here is the newlines between the `<button>`s). *This is completely normal and follows the* `inline-block` *spec*. This is *not* due to any `margin` or `padding`.

You can see that removing the whitespace (like in [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/uBBeX/1/)) will remove the "natural" (or "ghost") spacing between the elements.  You can find other techniques for mitigating this space at [this link](http://css-tricks.com/fighting-the-space-between-inline-block-elements/).

Some of the techniques involve wrapping the whitespace in comments:

```
<button>Text</button><!--
--><button>Text</button>
```

or moving the closing `>` between the closing tag and next opening tag:

```
<button>Text</button
><button>Text</button>
```

These techniques essentially remove the whitespace, so that there's none for the browser to render.

With some elements, like `<li>` (but not `<button>`), you can simply leave off the closing tag, as this is valid markup, and the browser will ignore all of that in-between whitespace between the elements:

```
<li>Item text
<li>Next item
```

Another technique involves setting `font-size: 0` on the element containing the `inline-block` or `inline` elements, as seen in [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/uBBeX/3/). With this technique, you have to then set the font size for child elements that actually have text, so that you can still see it! This can also mess up fonts based on `em` sizes, so it's not always the best solution, but it is a good solution that doesn't involve messing around with your markup.

Yet another technique involves setting a negative side (left or right) `margin` on your elements, but this is semantically incorrect usage of margins (they really shouldn't be negative, it's kind of hacky), and the magnitude of the margin value will depend on the font size rendering, which can vary between browsers and OSes, so this solution has a small chance of breaking (either showing a tiny gap, or overlapping the elements), and would not be something I suggest.

Of course, another solution is to keep a `float` rule :).

Comment: Thanks. I never knew that.

Comment: @XeroElixir A lot of people don't know this, so I always aim to explain it when I see it so that more people do know about it.

Answer (score 0):

Have you got a CSS reset script for your site: http://www.cssreset.com/ This will set the "natural" margins to 0 and will most probably solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

just like

```
*
{
  margin:0px;
  pading:0px; //optional if you need
}
```

using a css rest is also a good option.

Here you can find the most used css-reset http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/

Comment: I don't want to remove all margins, just with the buttons.